# Same function for jquery and php validation

Tags: php, jquery, validation, jquery-validate, codeigniter-2

So I have this problem. I'm doing a server side validation and a jquery validation.

In server side validation what I do is to use codeigniter's form_validation library, more specifically:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('documentn', 'Passport number', 'required|min_length[7]|max_length[20]|is_natural|callback_checkDocAndUser');
```

which needs a return true or return false.

I have this user edit form, to change user data. But there are some restrictions... user when stored in database has a unique passport number. I need to be able to change this passport number if it's wrong... but passport numbers should not be repeated on the database.

This is the php function that is called from callback_checkDocAndUser :

```
public function checkDocAndUser(){
    if ((isset($_POST['documentn'])) && (isset($_POST['id']))) {
        $dn = UserManager::getInstance()->checkUserDocument($_POST['documentn'],$_POST['id']);
        if ($dn) {
            //passport belongs to the user
            echo "true";
            // return true;
        }else{
            //does the passport entered belong to another user?
            $exists = UserManager::getInstance()->getByDocument($_POST['documentn']);
            if (!$exists) {
                //passport belongs to another user
                echo "true";
                // return true;
            }else{
                                    //passport number is free to use
                echo "false";
                // return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I put some "echo" in the functions. This is because I want to use the same function for a jQuery validation (which needs echo, doesn't work with "return").

```
       documentn: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 7,
                    maxlength: 20,
                    remote: {
                        url: '/admin/checkDocAndUser',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            id: function(){
                                return $('#id').val();
                            }                                
                        } 
                    }
                },
```

So how can I use the same function for both kind of validations...? is there a way to make jquery function receive a return..or codeigniter's function to receive an echo?

Comment: uuh, what are you trying to do? Is `id` to be a function or the value of `$('#id').val()`? I guess the last one. So why not just `id: $('#id').val()` ?

Comment: I'll check later if this works, but right now I'm more interested in the real question of my post. But thanks for the observation ;)

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. What is `documentn`? It is a member of some bigger object. What is that object and how is it being used? Are you using `$.ajax()`? Or maybe `$.post()`? Or something else?

Comment: documentn is the passport number (or user id)... I'm using remote rule ..which is a custom rule to check via ajax if a certain data exists or not in database. Plase notice that I mentioned that functions work fine and give the expected results, but only if I use echo for js file and return for codeigniter's callback function

Comment: I meant `documentn` is just a snippet out of a bigger statement. Show us the entire statement.

Comment: it's part of the rules for form validation plugin... there is no point to show the entire statement because problem is not in jquery, but in the server side function.

Comment: boy, you are stubborn, are you not? How do you expect to get help, while you are not telling us whether you are using `$.post()` or `$.ajax()` and you are not willing to share more code? You ask yourself if it is possible to have jQuery receive a return. How do you expect to get this question answered now, except with a blunt "Yes, it can"?

Comment: sorry..I'm willing to share the code, in fact take a look at all my previous questions. I told you I use the validation plugin, take a look at: http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/ I will post what you ask anyways--- and I'm not a boy ;)

Comment: Have you already tried BOTH `echo` first and then `return` at the same time ?

Comment: yes, but no success..

Comment: Hmm, it should work. Have you tried it like this  ? : `if (!$exists) { echo "true"; return true; } else { echo "false"; return false; }`

Comment: ok strangely.. I have tried again both sentences together and It worked. So please, @nl-x put the answer so I can choose it like the best :) and thank you for all

Comment: I think I have tried before with the return first and then the echo sentence...and that's bc it did not work

Comment: I would not do both `echo` and `return`... half the time you're sending `echo` when it's not needed and the other half you're `return`ing to nowhere.

Comment: @Sparky hey Sparky, I didn't do such thing! wasn't me

Comment: Ok, sorry.  Did you solve this yet?

Comment: Kind of. I want to try your solution but for now I can't. Soon I will and I let you know. Thanx for all :)

Answer (score 0):

I do the same thing in my CodeIgniter projects and the solution is quite simple.  The following answer is generically named where you only need to add your validation logic.

This answer follows [the DRY principle](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY) where your validation code is not repeated, as well as CodeIgniter structure.

This **MODEL** does the actual validation for **both** CodeIgniter (server-side) validation and jQuery Validate (client-side) `remote`...

```
// file name 'models/demo_model.php'

class Demo_model extends CI_Model {

    public function check_demo($params)
    {

        // insert your validation logic here...
        // the entirety of your validation logic, check the DB, etc.

        // if it passes validation
        return TRUE;

        // if it fails validation
        return FALSE;

    }

}
```

This **CONTROLLER** is *only* called by **client-side** `remote` for jQuery Validation...

```
// file name 'controllers/demo.php'

class Demo extends CI_Controller {

    public function remote_demo($params = FALSE)
    {

        // call the Model to do the actual validation
        $valid = $this->demo_model->check_demo($params);

        if ($valid)  
        {
            echo 'true';  // passes validation
        }
        else         
        {
            echo 'false'; // fails validation
        }

    }

}
```

This **LIBRARY** is *only* used for **server-side** validation by CodeIgniter...

```
// file name 'libraries/MY_Form_validation.php'

class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->ci =& get_instance();
    }

    public function demo_check($params)
    {

        $this->ci->form_validation->set_message('demo_check', 'The %s is incorrect.');  

        // call the Model to do the actual validation
        return $this->ci->demo_model->check_demo($params);

    }

}
```

The way it's organized, you'll have ONE centrally located validation function residing with your CodeIgniter Models.  I chose Models as the central location because the code is primarily interacting with the database.

The following uses the same Model function for both kinds of validation.

- **Server-side CodeIgniter validation**:  Calls the Model from `MY_Form_validation` and the Model will `return` `TRUE` or `FALSE` back to your other CodeIgniter Controllers as per your CodeIgniter validation rules.
- **Client-side jQuery Validate `remote`**:  Calls the Model from the Controller and the Model will `return` `TRUE` or `FALSE` back to the Controller.  Then the Controller function will `echo` `true` or `false` based on this boolean response from the Model.

Comment: `if (passes) return true; if (fails) return true;` ?

Comment: @nl-x, that was a typo... thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score -1):

```
Put an exit at the end of your function.

EDIT:

If you want to use the same set of validations for both client and server side validation, divide your call to two functions, one which handles client and the another which handles server. check the following code:
In you jquery function call url - admin/validate_form_client

function validate_form_client(){
   $op = $this->checkDocAndUser($_POST['documentn'],$_POST['id']);
   echo $op;
 exit;

}

function validate_form_server(){
   if ((isset($_POST['documentn'])) && (isset($_POST['id']))) {
    return $this->checkDocAndUser($_POST['documentn'],$_POST['id']);
}
}



public function checkDocAndUser($documentn,$id){

        $dn = UserManager::getInstance()->checkUserDocument($documentn,$id);
        if ($dn) {
            //id belongs to the user

            return true;
        }else{
            //does the id entered belong to another user?
            $exists = UserManager::getInstance()->getByDocument($documentn);
            if (!$exists) {
                // id number belongs to another user
                return "true";

            }else{
                                    //id number is free to use
                return "false";

            }
        }
    }
}

Note: the given function names are just for example. please follow standard practice in the variable and function naming conventions.
```

Comment: which function do you mean?

Comment: At the end of checkDocAndUser function.

Comment: An example code snippet would greatly help explain your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Validation functions always need to return a `boolean` value.

In your controller, try to retrieve the return value of the validation methods and echo "true" or "false" there.

Comment: I'm sorry I think I didn't understand what you mean... It doesn't work for server side validation if I put an echo "true" or echo "false" but it does work for jquery validation

Comment: At the place where you check if validation fails or not, try to echo a "true" or "false" yourself. You should never echo through validation methods.

Comment: sorry...still don't get it.

Comment: Can you post the code in your controller where you are validating the input?

Comment: oh you mean the result of the queries? yes, right away

Comment: Sorry, it's not the result of the queries. It's the controller code.

Comment: well then..my controller code is the one posted. In that function I do the validation